# Looking for a component that accepts a broad range of discrete values (e.g. 0 to 50 VDC) and outputs a LOGIC HIGH; otherwise output is LOGIC LOW

Tags: pcb, analog, components

I am looking for a component that will accept multiple discrete values ranging from 0 to 50 VDC,  but it doesn't have to be 50 VDC. I am looking for a broad range. This range could be 0 to 30 VDC or 0 to 60 VDC. Then, based on a set value of the discrete inputs (5 VDC or greater) will output a LOGIC HIGH and otherwise output is set to LOGIC LOW.

I could design a circuit easily for this purpose using a voltage divider and pulled down connected to a diode, but I am wanting a component that can accept multiple inputs and give multiple LOGIC outputs for each input. This will save room.

Comment: Please ask a valid question.

Comment: Are you saying that you are looking for a circuit that will give 0 for input in 0 to 5 V range and 1 for input > 5 V? "*... component that can accept multiple inputs and give multiple LOGIC outputs for each input.*" What does this mean? Please [Edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: Possibly comparators feeding into a ATTINY?  How many simultaneous inputs are you monitoring?

Comment: Also, you HAVE to set the minimum triggering voltage ABOVE ZERO, even if it's 10mV, otherwise you will have an unstable circuit or an oscillator. How high can the low level be? And how many inputs and outputs are you talking about?

Comment: how many inputs are you talking about?

Comment: 0 to 50 Vdc is one continuous value, not a bunch of discrete values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such component could be a plain comparator or an op-amp with a simple resistive voltage divider. 
You need to have a minimum value above 0V at which it will trigger. 
You could use a quad op-amp, so it's one IC with 4 circuits, giving you 4 inputs and outputs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXuX28.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Input voltage can go up to 60V easily, without damaging the comparator (LM339, for example). 
The input voltage may need to reach 0.1V to give you a logic zero at output.
The voltage provided to the output pull-up resistor sets your logic high output voltage. 
If you need to invert this and get logic high when input goes above 0.1V, you simply swap each inverting (-) and non-inverting (+) input with each other. 
To make it more integrated and slim, you could use "integrated resistors" (multiple resistors in a single package/component).

Comment: This gets me really close. Thank you.

Comment: @kcr2d2  You're welcome. If you need more details worked out, let me know. Also, don't forget to upvote and mark my answer as accepted if it works for you.

Comment: That is not going to work well, particularly if the comparators are used with a single supply voltage. The - inputs should be set to about ,025 volts with a divider network. As shown, there is no guarantee that the putpurs will go low with 0 volts in. You need to look up "input offset voltage" for your comparators. Also note that your 10K input resistors should be about 1/2 watt power dissipation.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast  I gave a rough outline of what can be done without going into all the details until necessary or asked for. I have indicated that 0.1V may be needed on the input to trigger the output, considering up to 9mV offset voltage combined with the 10/1 voltage divider. Other values and details can be hammered out if the questioner decides to go this route.

Comment: Re-reading the OP's question, it appears that they want to be able to set a threshold voltage, such as 5 VDC, above which the output is logic HIGH, and below which it will be LOW. So your suggested circuit would need a variable threshold voltage on the inverting inputs, and possibly separate adjustments for each comparator. Also, some positive feedback for hysteresis and stability, the magnitude of which should be provided by the OP as detailed specifications.